# How to access a variable from different class in try-catch block without namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces, try-catch

I am trying to access a variable from the different class, it works with class.variable in all classes except in try-catch blocks. In try-catch blocks it throwing me an error message  **The name Definitions doesn't exist in the correct context** , but when I specify with namespace.class.variable (Henn.Definitions.Location)then it works. Could it be possible to define without namespace in try-catch block ?

```
namespace Henn{
```

> Class Definitions

```
 public class Definitions
  {
        public static string Location = @"E:\Data\Misc\Contact.txt";
  }
```

> Class Process

```
public void Contact()
    {
 /* code */

  try {

/* code */

  string Location = Definitions.Location;

/* code */

  }

  catch {

  }
}
}
```

Comment: add `using Henn;` .........

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/IX7HZs

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a using namespace, and also Contact function should be part of a class

like this :

```
using Henn;

public class OtherClass
{
    public void Contact()
    {
       string Location = Definitions.Location;
    }
}
```

or put the classes in the same namespce

```
namespace Henn
{
    public class OtherClass
    {
        public void Contact()
        {
           string Location = Definitions.Location;
        }
    }
}
```